# Creating multiple instances of a model with one form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core

I'm building a form that creates a Model with a List of a different Model as an attribute.  Here's the model:

```
public class JobViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string JobTotal { get; set; }
        public bool Recurring { get; set; }
        public List<ServiceViewModel> ExtraServices { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Here's the ServiceViewModel class:

```
public class ServiceViewModel
    {
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public string ServiceTotal { get; set; }
    }
```

Any single JobViewModel can have from 0-4 extra services associated with it, so in the form, the user can add and remove extra service fields as needed.  Here's the form that creates a JobViewModel, along with some jQuery that lets the user add and remove extra service fields:
(EDIT: this is the _AddJobPartial partial view)

```
@{
    //create unique id's so the ajax toggle and delete scripts only affect one widget.
    var addJobWidgetId = "add-job-widget" + Model.JobId;
    var addServiceWidgetId = "add-service-widget" + Model.JobId;
    var addServiceButtonId = "add-service-button" + Model.JobId;
    var widgetTitleId = "widget-title" + Model.JobId;
    var deleteButtonId = "delete-button" + Model.JobId;
    var widgetId = "widget-" + Model.JobId;
}
<div class="row" id="@widgetId">
    <div class="border border-dark p-1 m-3">
        <div id="job-header" class="d-flex justify-content-between">

            <div>
                <label class="widget-title-text" id="@widgetTitleId" for="job-name">Job:</label>
                <input type="text" id="job-name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteButton" id="@deleteButtonId">X</button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="@addJobWidgetId" class="add-job-widget border border-dark">
          
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="total-cost-input">Job Total</label>
                <input type="text" id="total-cost-input" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="checkbox" value="recurring" id="recurring_box" name="recurring_box"/>
                <label for="recurring_box">Is this job recurring?</label>
            </div>

            <div class="p-1 extra-service-widget">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="@addServiceButtonId">
                    Add extra service
                </button>
                <!--EXTRA SERVICE-->
                <div id="@addServiceWidgetId">
                    
                </div>
                <!---->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<script>
    var servicesAdded = 0;

    $("#" + "@addServiceButtonId").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        servicesAdded++;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Daysheet/GetExtraServicePartial/" + servicesAdded.toString(),
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": requestVerificationToken
            }
        }).done(function (data, statusText, xhdr) {
            console.log("Done");
            $("#" + "@addServiceWidgetId").append(data);
        }).fail(function (xhdr, statusText, errorText) {
            console.log("Failed");
            $("#" + "@addServiceWidgetId").text(JSON.stringify(xhdr));
        });
        
    });

</script>
```

And here's the partial view that gets created when the "Add extra service" button on the above form is clicked:

```
@{
    var extraServiceListId = "extra-service-list" + Model.ServiceId;
    var extraServiceWidgetId = "extra-service-widget" + Model.ServiceId;
    var serviceTotalId = "service-total" + Model.ServiceId;
    var deleteServiceId = "delete-service" + Model.ServiceId;
}
<div class="p-1 border border-dark" id="@extraServiceWidgetId">
    <select id="@extraServiceListId">
        <option>Extra services...</option>
        <option value="purewater">Pure water</option>
        <option value="powerwashing">Power washing</option>
        <option value="roofwashing">Roof washing</option>
        <option value="awningclean">Awning clean</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="@serviceTotalId" placeholder="Service total" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteButton float-right" id="@deleteServiceId">X</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#' + '@deleteServiceId', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const elementToRemove = document.getElementById("@extraServiceWidgetId");
        jQuery(elementToRemove).slideToggle().fadeOut('slow', function () {
            elementToRemove.remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to know how to, when I submit the Job form, create a ServiceViewModel for every extra service Widget, and append them to the ExtraServices attribute on the JobViewModel.

I found something [here](https://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/09/preparing-list-of-objects-so-they-can.html) that offers something pretty close to what I need, but I'm not sure how this solution deals with a user who adds then deletes a field, which would result in an index error.  The link mentions that their solution is able to deal with that problem, but I don't understand where that's happening.

EDIT:

Here's the actual view with the form element.  This view has a button which adds the _AddJobPartial partial view, which I posted above.

This is GetCommission.cshtml, which is returned by one of the controller actions I've posted below.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Get Commission";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DaysheetSubLayout.cshtml";
}
@model GetCommissionsViewModel

<form method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 offset-1">
            <div id="jobs-div" class="flex-fill p-2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 offset-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center submit-jobs-wrapper">
            <input class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100 h-100 submit-jobs-button"
                   type="submit"
                   value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<input type="button" id="add-job-button" value="Add a Job" data-url="@Url.Action("GetAddJobsPartial", "Daysheet")" />


@section scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <script type="text/javascript">let requestVerificationToken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
        var numClicked = 0;
        $("#add-job-button").click(function () {
            console.log("Controller Button clicked");
            console.log($("#add-job-button").data("url"));
            numClicked++;
            console.log(numClicked);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Daysheet/GetAddJobsPartial/" + numClicked.toString(),
                headers: {
                    "RequestVerificationToken": requestVerificationToken
                }
            }).done(function (data, statusText, xhdr) {
                console.log("Done");
                $("#jobs-div").append(data);
            }).fail(function (xhdr, statusText, errorText) {
                console.log("Failed");
                $("#jobs-div").text(JSON.stringify(xhdr));
            });
        });</script>


}
```

Here's the relevant actions from my controller class:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetCommission(CrewDaysheetsListViewModel crewDaysheetsListViewModel)
        {
            var getCommissionsViewModel = new GetCommissionsViewModel { DaysheetIds = crewDaysheetsListViewModel.CommissionsViewDaysheetIds };
            return View(getCommissionsViewModel);
        }

        public IActionResult GetAddJobsPartial(string Id)
        {
            var addJobPartialViewModel = new AddJobPartialViewModel { JobId = Id};
            return PartialView("_AddJobsPartial", addJobPartialViewModel);
        }

        
        public IActionResult GetExtraServicePartial(string Id)
        {
            var extraServicePartialViewModel = new ExtraServicePartialViewModel { ServiceId = Id };
            return PartialView("_ExtraServicePartialView", extraServicePartialViewModel);
        }
```

The view models I use for these pages are pretty simple:

```
public class GetCommissionsViewModel
    {
        public List<string> DaysheetIds { get; set; }
    }

public class AddJobPartialViewModel
    {
        public string JobId { get; set; }
    
    }
public class ExtraServicePartialViewModel
    {
        public string ServiceId { get; set; }
    }
```

I use the JobId & serviceId (probably could combine these into a single ViewModel) with the partial views to give their elements unique id's so the delete button deletes the correct partial view, etc.  This number gets iterated with each button press in the  at the bottom of _AddJobPartial and _ExtraServicePartial.

Comment: Can you show the whole codes? Where are the JobId and ServiceId from? Also, I didn't see the form element in your view. If it is possible, you can show us the controller codes as well.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I was trying to be as focused as possible with the code I put in my question.  I added the code you asked about.